# Hide lines in Chart

Tags: c#, mschart

[image]

I want to remove indicated particular three vertical lines from graph except last line.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string Identification = context.Request.QueryString["identification"].ToString().Trim();
            DateTime BaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["baseDate"]);
            Guid? UserId = Guid.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["userId"]);
            Guid CustomerGuid = Guid.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["customerGuid"]);

            RootDataOperations root = new RootDataOperations();
            int FedID = root.GetFedIDByCustomerGuid(CustomerGuid);

            Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea("ChartArea1");

            Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");

            int width = 600, height = 500;
            Chart1.Width = width;
            Chart1.Height = height;

            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 10;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 10;



            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataOperations data = new DataOperations(FedID, Guid.Empty);
            List<UserQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison> userQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison = new List<UserQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison>();
            userQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison = data.GetUserQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison(Identification, UserId.Value, BaseDate);

            DataTable dt = ToDataTable<UserQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison>(userQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Legend legend = new Legend();
                legend.Docking = Docking.Top;
                legend.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                legend.IsTextAutoFit = false;
                Chart1.Legends.Add(legend);
                Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;

                var IEtable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

                Chart1.DataBindTable(userQuarterlyTopPerformerComparison, "Quarter");

                //string userName = dt.Rows[0]["CUNAME"].ToString() + " (Current User)";
                Guid currentuser = UserId.Value;
                string userName = data.GetUserByID(currentuser).Name1 + " (Current User)";

                string cuname = string.Empty;
                int i = 0;

                Dictionary<string, Color> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
                dictionary.Add(userName, System.Drawing.Color.DimGray);

                List<DataRow> distinctUsers = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "TU1NAME", "TU2NAME", "TU3NAME").AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToList();

                int count = 0;
                foreach (DataRow dr in distinctUsers)
                {
                    Color colour = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    int drCount = 0;
                    foreach (object oObject in dr.ItemArray)
                    {
                        if (dr[drCount].ToString() != "" && !dictionary.ContainsKey(dr[drCount].ToString()))
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            }
                            if (count == 1)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            }
                            if (count == 2)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
                            }
                            if (count == 3)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
                            }
                            if (count == 4)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
                            }
                            if (count == 5)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
                            }
                            if (count == 6)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
                            }
                            if (count == 7)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
                            }
                            if (count == 8)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Coral;
                            }
                            if (count == 9)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
                            }
                            if (count == 10)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.DarkKhaki;
                            }
                            if (count == 11)
                            {
                                colour = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                            }

                            dictionary.Add(dr[drCount].ToString(), colour);

                            count++;

                        }
                        drCount++;
                    }
                }


                Legend legend1 = null;
                foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys)
                {
                    legend1 = new Legend();
                    legend1.Docking = Docking.Top;

                    legend1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    legend1.IsTextAutoFit = false;
                    Chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
                    Chart1.Legends[1].CustomItems.Add(new LegendItem(key, dictionary[key], ""));
                }

                foreach (Series series in Chart1.Series)
                {
                    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
                    Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
                }

                if (distinctUsers.Count >= 1)
                {
                    Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = dictionary[userName];
                    Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Label = userName;
                    if (dt.Rows[0]["TU1NAME"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[1].Points[0].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[0]["TU1NAME"].ToString()];
                        Chart1.Series[1].Points[0].Label = dt.Rows[0]["TU1NAME"].ToString()+" (Top 1)";
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows[0]["TU2NAME"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[2].Points[0].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[0]["TU2NAME"].ToString()];
                        Chart1.Series[2].Points[0].Label = dt.Rows[0]["TU2NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 2)";
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows[0]["TU3NAME"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[3].Points[0].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[0]["TU3NAME"].ToString()];
                        Chart1.Series[3].Points[0].Label = dt.Rows[0]["TU3NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 3)";
                    }

                    if (distinctUsers.Count >= 2)
                    {
                        Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Color = dictionary[userName];
                        Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Label = userName;
                        if (dt.Rows[1]["TU1NAME"].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            Chart1.Series[1].Points[1].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[1]["TU1NAME"].ToString()];
                            Chart1.Series[1].Points[1].Label = dt.Rows[1]["TU1NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 1)";
                        }
                        if (dt.Rows[1]["TU2NAME"].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            Chart1.Series[2].Points[1].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[1]["TU2NAME"].ToString()];
                            Chart1.Series[2].Points[1].Label = dt.Rows[1]["TU2NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 2)";
                        }
                        if (dt.Rows[1]["TU3NAME"].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            Chart1.Series[3].Points[1].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[1]["TU3NAME"].ToString()];
                            Chart1.Series[3].Points[1].Label = dt.Rows[1]["TU3NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 3)";
                        }

                        if (distinctUsers.Count >= 3)
                        {
                            Chart1.Series[0].Points[2].Color = dictionary[userName];
                            Chart1.Series[0].Points[2].Label = userName;
                            if (dt.Rows[2]["TU1NAME"].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[1].Points[2].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[2]["TU1NAME"].ToString()];
                                Chart1.Series[1].Points[2].Label = dt.Rows[2]["TU1NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 1)";
                            }
                            if (dt.Rows[2]["TU2NAME"].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[2].Points[2].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[2]["TU2NAME"].ToString()];
                                Chart1.Series[2].Points[2].Label = dt.Rows[2]["TU2NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 2)";
                            }
                            if (dt.Rows[2]["TU3NAME"].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[3].Points[2].Color = dictionary[dt.Rows[2]["TU3NAME"].ToString()];
                                Chart1.Series[3].Points[2].Label = dt.Rows[2]["TU3NAME"].ToString() + " (Top 3)";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }



                string fileLoacation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images") + "/test.png";
                int counter = 1;
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLoacation))
                {
                    fileLoacation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images") + "/test" + counter + ".png";
                    counter++;
                }
                Chart1.SaveImage(fileLoacation, ChartImageFormat.Png);

                Image img = Image.FromFile(fileLoacation);
                Image _img = new Bitmap(width, height, img.PixelFormat);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_img);
                g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                g.Dispose();
                img.Dispose();
                MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
                _img = _img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                _img.Save(str, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                _img.Dispose();
                str.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                str.Dispose();
                str.Close();
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileLoacation);
                context.Response.ContentType = ".png";

                //string strGridVal = string.Empty;
                //strGridVal = "<table border=\"1\">";
                //for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                //{
                //    strGridVal += "<tr><td>" + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString()+ "</td></tr>";
                //}
                //strGridVal += "</table>";
                //context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                //context.Response.Write(strGridVal);
                //context.Response.ContentType = dt.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Response.End();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nice diagram. Where is the code?

Comment: update question with relevant code

Comment: did you tried chartSeries.Appearance.Border.Width = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid lines are controlled with the `MajorGrid` and `MinorGrid` properties of the `Axis` object. Set the `Enabled` property to `false` to disable them.